# excel formula to search for text and then paste corresponding text into new columns

Tags: excel, gps

I have two excel spreadsheets: one ("data entry") for entering GPS waypoint IDs and corresponding data (time taken, compass bearings from waypoints, observations, etc.); and the other ("gps data") is just the spreadsheet of the waypoints, downloaded from the GPS unit, which has the corresponding coordinates for each of the waypoint IDs.  I need to add two columns to the "data entry" spreadsheet that will search the "gps data" spreadsheet for the specific waypoint IDs mentioned in the "data entry" spreadsheet ("waypoint ID" column), and then paste the corresponding coordinate values (lat and long, two different columns) from the "gps data" sheet into two new columns in the "data entry" sheet.

So basically I just need the "data entry" sheet to have the coordinates as well, without manually copying and pasting the coordinate rows from one sheet to the other.  This is all for making the data entry sheet usable for the LOAS program that triangulates bearings on wildlife, in case you're familiar with that software.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Index \ Match may work as well, if the coordinates are not to the right of the waypoint ID column.

Comment: Thanks, vlookup was perfect, I knew there was a simple solution.